# LoadImage() function not works

Tags: c++

I have a problem with LoadImage.(Invalid Handle Error*)

```cpp
HDC screen = CreateCompatibleDC(0);

HDC imageDC = CreateDC(0, 0, 0, 0);

HBITMAP filebmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,_T("C:\\file.bmp"),IMAGE_BITMAP,200,200, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);

SelectObject(imageDC, filebmp);

BOOL d = BitBlt(screen, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, imageDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

This is my main Code. Where am I doing wrong?
I searched about it but couldn't find any solution for this.

Comment: How do you know that LoadImage is not working? Have you checked the `filebmp` variable (because you haven't in the code you posted above).

Comment: yes. it gives invalid handle error(now i used GetLastError)

Comment: Either file doesn't exist, or it's not a valid bitmap file or it's not a format that LoadImage can accept. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: What return value did you get from GetLastError?

Comment: "I have a problem with LoadImage"  - and what exactly is the problem? Please don't add relevant information in comments, update your question so that it contains all necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Problem you may have is that your bitmap file is invalid, you can't just change .jpg to .bmp, your image needs to be saved as bmp.